# Make a Firebase Child ref with react Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

How can I make a reference to a key using a relative path ? I want to target the "likes" child of item1/items2, etc...those are key I created myself. 
Here is my json file:

```
{
    "items": {
        "items1": {
            "french": "fdjsfd",
            "english": "feeds",
            "english_erudite": "fdsfds",
            "likes":"0",
            },
          "items2": {
            "french": "fdfsd",
            "english": "fdsfsd",
            "english_erudite": "feeds",
            "likes":"0",
            }
          }
}
```

Right now I have this, but it adds a new child to the node "items" instead of going to items>items1>likes:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref();



var likes_words = ref.child("items").child("???").child("likes");


likes_words.transaction(function(currentLike) {
   return currentLike + 1;
});
}
```

Comment: Which item's count are you trying to increase?

Answer (score 1):

Just adjust your code to this

```
 var ref = firebase.database().ref();

            var likes_words = ref.child("items").once('value');

                likes_words.then(items => {
                    items.forEach(item => {

                       //for each item do this
                       let currentlike = item.val().likes;
                     ref.child("items/"+item.key+"/likes").update((currentlike+1));

                    })
               });
```

Comment: That will work in single-user situations, but I'd recommend [using a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions) for a more robust solution. `ref.child("items/"+item.key+"/likes").transaction(function(currentLikes) {
  return (currentLikes || 0) + 1;
});`

Comment: It throw a syntax error  < Syntax Error unexpected character "> for your solution @FrankvanPuffelen 
It points this line : 
ref.child("items/"+item.key+"/likes").transaction(function(c‌​urrentLikes)

Comment: As far as I can see there is no `>` in the code I left in my comment. So it seems unlikely that this change alone introduced that error. If you can't find the cause, edit your question to include the [minimal code that reproduces the error](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you @EmekaObianom, could not solve the issue but could find a code that works;-)

Comment: You can post your solution link also so that it would help someone. post it as a link here on the comment.